# Submit form to rewritten URLs?

Tags: forms, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create nice URL's for my Magento search form, to make:

```
http://domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=KEYWORD
```

look like this:

```
http://domain.com/search/KEYWORD
```

I have written this is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ /catalogsearch/result/?q=$1 [QSA,P,NC]
```

Which works nicely, when I type in `http://domain.com/search/KEYWORD` it displays the results as it should.

BUT...

I can't workout how to get my search form to go to the nice format URL, it still goes to the original.

My search form is currently like this:

```
<form id="search_form" action="http://domain.com/catalogsearch/result/" method="get">
        <input id="search" type="search" name="q" value="KEYWORD" maxlength="128">
        <button type="submit">search</button>
</form>
```

Any point in the right direction much appreciated.

Comment: where did you used rewriteRule

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things going on here, so let me try to explain the best I can.

First and foremost, your main issue is the generation of this new "pretty" search URL. When you use a `<form>` with `method="GET"`, each input (i.e. `<input name="q">`) will get appended to the form's action as a query parameter (you'll get `/search?q=foo` instead of `/search/foo`).

In order to fix this, you need to do two things:

1. Change your form tag to look like this:

   ```
   <form id="search_form" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('search'); ?>" method="GET">
   ```

   This will ensure that the form is submitted to `/search` instead of `/catalogsearch/result`. (You'll still get a `?q=foo`, though, and that will be resolved in #2.)
2. Add a bit of JavaScript which hijacks the form submission and forms the desired URL:

   ```
   var form = document.getElementById('search_form'),
       input = document.getElementById('search');

   form.onsubmit = function() {
       // navigate to the desired page
       window.location = form.action + input.value;

       // don't actually submit the form
       return false;
   };
   ```

That'll get you up and running, but there are still some other issues which you should resolve.

Using `RewriteRule` based rewrites with Magento does not work well. I haven't quite figured out the technical reason for this, but I've had the same trouble that you're having. The reason that your rewrite works with the `P` flag is because [the `P` flag turns the rewrite into a proxy request](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p). This means that your web server will make another request to itself with the new URL, which avoids the typical `RewriteRule` trouble you'd run into.

So, how do you utilize a custom pretty URL without using `RewriteRule`? You use Magento's internal rewrite logic! Magento offers regex-based rewrite logic similar to `RewriteRule` through its configuration XML:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <some_unique_identifier>
                <from><![CDATA[#/search/(.*)/?$#]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[/catalogsearch/result/index/q/$1/]]></to>
                <complete />
            </some_unique_identifier>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
</config>
```

By putting that configuration in one of your modules, Magento will internally rewrite requests of the form `/search/foo` to `/catalogsearch/result/index/q/foo/`. Note that you have to use Magento's custom parameter structure (name-value pairs separated by `/`), as it will not parse query string parameters after it performs this internal rewrite. Also note that you have to specify the full module-controller-action trio (`/catalogsearch/result/index/`) because otherwise `q` would be interpreted as an action name, not a parameter name.

This is much better than using a proxy request because it doesn't issue a secondary request, and the rewrite happens in Magento's core route handling logic.

This should be enough to get you completely up and running on the right path. However, if you're interested, you could take this *one* step further.

By using the above techniques, you'll end up with three URLs for your searches: `/search/foo`, `/catalogsearch/result/?q=foo`, and `/catalogsearch/result/q/foo`. This means that you essentially have three pages for each search query, all with the same content. This is not great for SEO purposes. In order to combat this drawback, you can create a 301 permanent redirect from the second two URLs to redirect to your pretty URL, or you can use a `<link rel="canonical">` tag to tell search engines that your pretty URL is the main one.

Anyways, I hope that all of this helps and puts you on the right track!

Comment: thanks for the in depth answer, I am trying to get this working however I cant seem to get the pretty URL's working using just the XML config. Where would you advise I place this XML? I added it to the catalogsearch config.xml file but no joy. I dont have any custom modules.

Comment: You should create a custom module for this. You only need an XML file (like `Mycompany_Mymodule.xml`) in `app/etc/modules` to tell Magento about your module, and then another XML file to act as your config file (like `app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/etc/config.xml`) with the configuration in my answer.

Comment: Ive done exactly as you say, and checked it over and over but it still doesnt appear to work. Could I be missing something obvious? Tried the module under community and local, refreshed caches etc, still just getting a 404.

Comment: I set this up locally and tried it myself, and sure enough, I got a 404 as well. Upon further investigation, it turns out that my rewrite was incorrect. `/catalogsearch/result/q/foo/` is interpreted as the `q` action of the `result` controller of the `catalogsearch` module, which is obviously incorrect. I've updated my answer with the correct `<rewrite>` configuration (both the `<from>` and the `<to>` were updated), please take another look. It works great for me now, sorry about that!